# Trigger on new data loaded by ajax didnt work

Tags: jquery, ajax, triggers

I have some data Example input type file that **loaded by ajax**.

Now I want **"when click on submit file upload that loaded handle trigger('click')"**
but it doesn't work :(
some one help me :(

This is my codes :

> $('body').on('click', '#uploadfile', function(e){  e.preventDefault();
>   $('#uploader.trigger('click'); });

This trigger didn't work:

> $('#uploader').trigger('click');

Comment: return false from your anonymous function

Comment: now what could i do ?????
i need trigger click file upload

Comment: can you create a fiddle please

Answer (score 1):

Use `.delegate()` function:

```
$('body').delegate('#uploadfile', 'click', function(){ $('#uploader.trigger('click'); });
```

> .delegate()

**Description**: Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements.

**Reference:** http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Hope this helped.

*Pablo.*